# R: Percentagewise interaction of variables by group

Tags: r

Below, I have a simplified version of my data frame, which actually has more rows and columns.

```
df <- data.frame(category=c("con","con","con","con","con","con",
"tre","tre","tre","tre","tre","tre"),
answer=c(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1),
female=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0),
married=c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0))
```

I need to crete a new data frame in R, which

- is grouped by the variable "category", and
- shows the percentages of the dependent variable "answer" under each independent variable.

And, below is the data frame that I try to create.

```
needed <- data.frame(category=c("con", "tre"), 
female=c(50, 33.33),     
married=c(66.66, 0))
```

For example, it shows that

- 33.33 percent of the females in the treatment group answered the question.
- 66.66 percent of the married people in the cotrol group answered the question.
- etc.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible `dplyr` implementation which will operate over all you columns at once

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum(.[answer == 1])/sum(.)), -answer)

# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# 
#   category    female   married
#     (fctr)     (dbl)     (dbl)
# 1      con 0.5000000 0.6666667
# 2      tre 0.3333333 0.0000000
```

You can do a similar thing with `data.table` but you will get an additional `answer` column too as a result

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x[answer == 1])/sum(x)), by = category]
#    category answer    female   married
# 1:      con      1 0.5000000 0.6666667
# 2:      tre      1 0.3333333 0.0000000
```

---

Issue [#495](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495) is solved now with [this recent commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/68091d851d400b4d768f3c41c0210da76945c12b), we can now do this just fine:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x[answer==1])/sum(x)), by=category, .SDcols=-"answer"]
#    category    female   married
# 1:      con 0.5000000 0.6666667
# 2:      tre 0.3333333 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the necessary base-R idea:

```
rowsum((df$answer & df[c("female", "married")]) + 0L, df$category) /
rowsum(df[c("female", "married")], df$category)
#       female   married
#con 0.5000000 0.6666667
#tre 0.3333333 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `split` with `colSums`.  We `split` the dataset by 'category' to get a `list` output.  We can loop using `sapply` and get the `colSums` for the subset of columns and the corresponding rows where answer is 1, divide by the `colSums` of the 'con', 'tre' output.

```
 t(sapply(split(df, df$category), function(x)
           100*with(x, colSums(x[answer==1,3:4])/colSums(x[3:4]))))
 #      female  married
 #con 50.00000 66.66667
 #tre 33.33333  0.00000
```